# Google Maps Api v2. What is a range of zoom value?

Tags: android, google-maps

To get zoom level:

```
float zoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
```

What is a range of zoom value? min? max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

min value 2.0
max value 21.0

for detail visit :
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#public-methods